# How to fix The specified module 'dockercompose' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory?

Tags: windows, powershell

In my Powershell

```
Import-Module dockercompose
Import-Module : The specified module 'dockercompose' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

 Get-module -ListAvailable shows

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        Deployment                          {PopulateKeyVaultCertificateDataPackages, EntityLogin, CreateOrUpdateConfiguration, GetAdAccount...}
Script     0.0        Deployment-Extra                    {LookupRepositoryInfos, IncrementCsprojVersion, RemoteDesktop, InstallNewtonsoftJson...}
```

and

```
Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
```

and

```
Directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules


ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   1.0.0.0    AppBackgroundTask                   {Disable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Enable-AppBackgroundTaskDiagnosticLog, Set-AppBackgroundTaskResourcePolicy, Unregister-AppBackgroundTask...}
Manifest   2.0.0.0    AppLocker                           {Get-AppLockerFileInformation, Get-AppLockerPolicy, New-AppLockerPolicy, Set-AppLockerPolicy...}
```

From command line

```
 docker-compose --version
Docker Compose version v2.1.1
```

When I run docker-compose

```
Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

Docker Compose

Options:
      --ansi string                Control when to print ANSI control
                                   characters ("never"|"always"|"auto")
                                   (default "auto")
      --compatibility              Run compose in backward compatibility mode
      --env-file string            Specify an alternate environment file.
  -f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files
      --profile stringArray        Specify a profile to enable
      --project-directory string   Specify an alternate working directory
                                   (default: the path of the Compose file)
  -p, --project-name string        Project name
```

How to add dockercompose to my PATH?

Comment: What happens when you just run `docker-compose` from the PowerShell prompt (no `Import-Module`)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Added,take a look

Comment: Looks like it's already in your path then :)